# PHP MySQL join table as JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have two different tables – one called "products" which contains information about products for an online shop and another table called "images" which contains the respective product images (several images for each product).
I want to join the table "images" on the main table "products" and output the result in JSON format.

The table "products" looks like the following (simplified):

```
id  | name
----|--------
57  | apple
58  | tomato
59  | ...
```

And the table "images" for the product images:

```
img_id | img         | p_id | listorder
-------|-------------|------|----------
32     | apple1.jpg  | 57   | 1
33     | apple2.jpg  | 57   | 2
34     | tomato1.jpg | 58   | 1
35     | ...         | ...  | ...
```

By now, my Query is this:

```
$sql = "SELECT
        p.id as p_id,
        p.name as p_name,
        i.*
        FROM products p
        JOIN (SELECT * FROM images WHERE listorder=1)
        AS i ON (i.p_id = p.id)";
```

Hence the output (after fetching the data into an array and converting to JSON) looks something like this:

```
[{
  "id": "57",
  "name": "apple",
  "img": "apple1.jpg"
}, {
  "id": "58",
  "name": "tomato",
  "img": "tomato1.jpg"
}]
```

So my question is: How can I output the following?

```
[{
  "id": "57",
  "name": "apple",
  "img": [{"img_id": "32","img": "apple1.jpg"}, {"img_id": "33","img": "apple2.jpg"}]
}, {
  "id": "58",
  "name": "tomato",
  "img": [{"img_id": "34","img": "tomato1.jpg"}]
}]
```

Comment: How did you obtain your current JSON output?  Is this from MySQL or PHP?

Comment: ` WHERE listorder=1` limits it to one image per product

Comment: most probably manually i think 

you would have to make your own array and json encode that i think using multiple queries

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    p.id as p_id,
    p.name as p_name,
    group_concat(concat('{"img_id":"',i.img_id,'"img":"',i.img,'"}') separator ',') as img
FROM products p
    JOIN (SELECT * FROM images WHERE listorder=1)
    AS i ON (i.p_id = p.id)
GROUP BY p.id,p.name
```

Answer (score -2):

Decode the JSON to Array and merge them, then Encode to JSON Again. Try doing it

**Two Functions:**

[array_merge($array1, $array2)](http://php.net/array_merge)

[json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - while it is often useful to link to documentation elsewhere online, it would also be really helpful if you could demonstrate with some code how these functions can be used to approach the original question.